# Is there a way to create a DynamicObject that supports an Interface?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic-proxy, dynamicobject

Can I define a class which derives from DynamicObject and supports an interface (ICanDoManyThings) without having to implement each method in the interface?

I'm trying to make a dynamic proxy object, and want the method invocations on this class to be handled by the implementation of MyProxyClass.TryInvokeMember, which may or may not pass them on to a wrapped object.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically implementing an interface in .NET 4.0 (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974736/dynamically-implementing-an-interface-in-net-4-0-c)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[ImpromptuInterface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) does exactly this and it works with ANY IDynamicMetaObjectProvider including DynamicObject subclasses and ExpandoObject.

```
using ImpromptuInterface;
using ImpromptuInterface.Dynamic;

public interface IMyInterface{

   string Prop1 { get;  }

    long Prop2 { get; }

    Guid Prop3 { get; }

    bool Meth1(int x);
}
```

...

```
//Dynamic Expando object
dynamic tNew = Build<ExpandoObject>.NewObject(
         Prop1: "Test",
         Prop2: 42L,
         Prop3: Guid.NewGuid(),
         Meth1: Return<bool>.Arguments<int>(it => it > 5)
);

IMyInterface tActsLike = Impromptu.ActLike<IMyInterface>(tNew);
```

Linfu won't actually use DLR based objects and rather uses it's own naive late binding which gives it a *SERIOUS* performance cost. Clay does use the dlr but you have to stick with Clay objects which are designed for you to inject all behavior into a ClayObject which isn't always straightforward.

Comment: Does this work if I write my own expando and call `ActLike`? Like, `dynamic tNew = new ExpandoObject(); tNew.Prop1 = "Test";` ...etc... and `Impromptu.ActLike<IMyInterface>(tNew);` ?

Comment: Yes it works with any `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`, as it uses the C# `dynamic` keyword api's.

Answer (score 3):

With [Clay](http://clay.codeplex.com/), you can.

An example:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    string Prop1 { get; }

    long Prop2 { get; }

    Guid Prop3 { get; }

    Func<int, bool> Meth { get; }
}

//usage:

dynamic factory = new ClayFactory();
var iDynamic = factory.MyInterface
(
    Prop1: "Test",
    Prop2: 42L,
    Prop3: Guid.NewGuid(),
    Meth: new Func<int, bool>(i => i > 5)
);

IMyInterface iStatic = iDynamic;
```

[This article](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/08/18/clay-malleable-c-dynamic-objects-part-2.aspx) shows few more ways to achieve this.

Comment: It's better to install ClaySharp from nuget rather than Clay since the latter has a dependency with Castle.Core project (unfortunately doesn't work with latest Castle.Core as well) while the former has no dependency issues.

Comment: While Clay offers a great deal of flexibility I like the approach of Impromptu. Pretty straightforward. Another case, Clay doesn't play well with interfaces having methods.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [LinFu's proxies, mixins and duck typing](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/LinFuPart1.aspx).

Comment: linfu uses it's own invention for a DynamicObject that was pre-DLR. Upside is that it works with .net 3.5, downside it can be painfully slow.